# how to convert mp4 to divx?

Tags: dvd, mpeg4, avi

I have the following DVD player - http://www.lg.com/ae/video/lg-DP542 - 
and I want to convert my mp4 files into DivX as that is what my player supports. I tried VLC's converter and Handshake but had no luck. Can you help?

Comment: What settings did you use with Handbrake? Have you tried the MP4 directly? The product page advertises support for Divx HD, which is essentially H.264/AAC in Matroska (MKV), so ISO MP4 container might work.

Answer (score 2):

The good old ffmpeg gives you the power ;)

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v libxvid output.avi
```

You can obviously fine tweak the command line with bitrate, audio in mp3 and so on.

es:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v libxvid -b:v 512k -c:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 4 output.avi
```

This is for a single bitrate use, where you use a constant bitrate for every frame.

Otherwise you could go for a 2 pass bitrate where the 1st pass is used only for determine where is the best for allocate more data...

But you can also convert in xvid/divx Mpeg 4 Layer 2 using a quality preset where you don't put directly the bitrate wanted but just ask for a minimum visual quality respected where you will be less concerned about the final file size (it will be discovered only at the end).

`-qscale:v 3` instead of the `-b:v 512k` that i used above

Comment: Thanks for information. I haven't tried out this as I found a solution with Freemake.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with 'Freemake video converter' http://www.freemake.com/ 
Where I used 'Convert to AVI' with XVID settings and it works. Anyway yes capacity is more than mp4.

Answer (score 0):

I use [MacX Video Converter Pro](http://www.macxdvd.com/mac-video-converter-pro/) to solve this problem. This converter is great to handle MP4 and AVI formats video conversion. And I also use to convert other formats, such as MKV, WMV, MOV, FLV, etc. I love the high quality after conversion, and the converting speed is so fast. You may have a try.